# How to disable button based on state?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my reactjs app I have a button that is disabled/enabled based on a state value:

```
<button disabled={this.state.modelvalue === 0 ? true : false} onClick={this.showMessage}>Select</button>
```

The modelvalue state is set by changing the select value:

```
<div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
            <select name="" id="" value={this.state.modelvalue} onChange={this.handleChangeModel}>
              <option value ="0">plse select value</option>
              <option value ="1">One</option>
            </select>
      </div>
</div>

 handleChangeModel(event) {
    this.setState({modelvalue: event.target.value});
 }
```

The handleChangeModel sets the state.modelvalue but for some reason when you change from 'one' back to 'plse select value' the button does not get disabled? Even though the state.modelvalue is 0 again?

Comment: just a suggestion ... for readability, I often use a buttonState object eg. const buttonstate = { disabled: ( this.state.modelvalue == 0 ? true : false) } and spread it on the button <button {...buttonstate} ... to get less clutter in the jsx-part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the selected value will be a `string` not a `number`, you need to write the condition like this:

```
disabled={this.state.modelvalue === '0'}   //string comparison
```

**Update:**

As suggested by @RobG, instead of using `===` (check value with type) use `==` (check value without type) to check the value, it will work:

```
disabled={this.state.modelvalue == 0}
```

Comment: Or `this.state.modelvalue == 0`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks, yes we can check by `==` also, updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modelvalue: null
    }

    this.handleChangeModel = this.handleChangeModel.bind(this);
  }

 handleChangeModel(event) {
    this.setState({modelvalue: event.target.value});
 }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
            <select name="" id="" value={this.state.modelvalue} onChange={this.handleChangeModel}>
              <option value ="0">plse select value</option>
              <option value ="1">One</option>
            </select>
      </div>

      <button disabled={this.state.modelvalue === "0" ? true : false} onClick={this.showMessage}>Select</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

2 things that you missed:
1) Adding this.handleChangeModel = this.handleChangeModel.bind(this); in constructor so that you can bind context of this in handleChangeModel since its a callback method
2) Use this.state.modelvalue === "0" instead of this.state.modelvalue === 0

Comment: Thanks. This helps me in my React Native project.